# How to get viewstates from same array point via regular expression

Tags: regex, jmeter

I want to get viewstates from diffent types.

One is in html :

```
id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0" value="GKILT9kVeCjgGmRutjLtzOO840X+LyZk"  autocomplete="off" />
```

The other is in xml :

```
id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0"><![CDATA[GKILT9kVeCjgGmRutjLtzOO840X+LyZk]]></update>
```

When I run my regular expression, the result array is diffrent. The One result is array[1][3] the other result is array[1][4]

My Regex like this :

```
id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:[\d]+"(><!\[CDATA\[(.+)\]\]|\svalue=")(.+)(\]\]><|"\sautocomplete)
```

How can I get result same array data?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a single Regular Expression to work for both scenarios you can use something like:

```
(?:(id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:(\d+)" value="(.+?)"  autocomplete="off" />)|(id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:(\d+)"><\!\[CDATA\[(.+?)\]\]></update>))
```

This will match ViewState value from both inputs as it evidenced by the `RegExp Tester` mode of the [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener.

[image: JMeter Regular Expression Extractor Demo]

More information:

- [JMeter: Regular Expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Perl 5 Regex Cheat sheet](https://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet)
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)

Comment: Hello Dmitri, Thank you for your response. It works but I have a problem that one is in thirth dimension ant the other is fifth dimension. I want to both is same dimension. Other wise I have to write my regex extractor seperately. This is more complex to manage.

Comment: By the way I call regex extractor different http requests.